# Function for dataset manipulation in R: convert from 1 column to 2columns

Tags: r, dplyr, reshape

What function I should use if I want to convert from data like this

[image]

Data like this

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to reshape data from long to wide format](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57013551/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try reshaping and please next time include data using `dput()` not screenshots:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
#Data
df <- data.frame(Country=rep(c('Spain','Croatia'),5),
                 quarter=as.Date(c('2017-03-31','2017-03-31',
                                   '2017-06-30','2017-06-30',
                                   '2017-09-30','2017-09-30',
                                   '2017-12-31','2017-12-31',
                                   '2018-03-31','2018-03-31')),
                 employment_index=runif(10,98,107))
#Code
new <- df %>% pivot_wider(names_from = Country,values_from=employment_index)
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 5 x 3
  quarter    Spain Croatia
  <date>     <dbl>   <dbl>
1 2017-03-31  99.8    99.1
2 2017-06-30 103.    105. 
3 2017-09-30  98.7   103. 
4 2017-12-31 103.    104. 
5 2018-03-31 100.     99.9
```

Comment: Thank you! Will use dput() next time and also will use pivot_wider function.

Comment: @Gina Fantastic Gina, always a pleasure helping!